# How can I link questions together in seq2seq module?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning

I am working with the tensorflow seq2seq module. In that questions we ask are independent from each other. But if we want to make conversational seq2seq modules we really need to keep track of previous questions.This can be done if we feed all the questions that asked before in to the module. But this is not practical. 
**Is that can be done with keeping some cashing on input and outputs for each questions and then feed it back?**